# Как скрыть строку компиляции в intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите пожалуйста как скрыть эту строку, я уже где только не искал, но нашел только как ее сделать в одну линию
[image]
Нужно чтобы стало хотя бы вот так
[image]

Comment: У вас не получится её скрыть, она обязательна для информирования программиста. Правда это то, как я знаю. Может, у вас всё же получится, но не советую тратить на это время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы скрыть эту строку нужно щелкнуть на нее правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать пункт `Fold Lines Like This`, в открывшемся окне можно будет настроить паттерн в каком случае строка будет свернута, например если строка начинается с "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines"

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то это строка нужна... Ну если уж совсем мешает по религиозным соображениям, то можно окно превратить из `docked` (*прикрепленная*) в `floating` (*плавающую*) и утащить ее куда-нибудь - ну например в самый низ, чтобы ее почти не было видно.

Я когда прогаю за десктопом, обычно мешающие окна утаскиваю на другой монитор (их у меня 2) - удобно.

Answer (score 0):

слева в этой панеле тыкаешь в кнопку [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и у тебя эта строка станет в одну строчку + по этой строчке можно жмакнуть `ctrl + -(кнопка минус)` и тогда она станет сложенной

Comment: `ctrl + -(кнопка минус)` почему то не работает, ничего не изменяется